# PHP 301 redirect multiple URLs

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to move multiple dynamic URLs using a php 301 redirect, not htaccess.

I can't work out how to put it together though as I'm a little out of my depth, this is all have so far.

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.new-website/new-folder/ $url="http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$url=str_replace('http://www.website.com/old-folder/','',$url);
echo $url; "); 
?>
```

Old URLs: http://www.website.com/old-folder/news-article/full.php?=*anything*

New URLs: http://www.new-website.com/new-folder/news-article/full.php?=*anything*

I want to insert anything that comes after the second / of the current URL into the Header Location

Anything after /old-folder/ will be different each time.

In simple terms I am trying to do this:

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.new-website/new-folder/ *insert end of URL from current address bar here* "); 
?>
```

Comment: Use ```header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently")```.

Comment: You should consider using .htaccess for doing this, as your option might be prone to HTTP header splitting.

Comment: Use .htaccess or the vhost conf file to define your rewrites as it will be a lot lighter on the server. (Though I'm guessing you don't understand the rewrite module and is why you are intending to do it in php?)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a variable inside the header function, then trying to call functions inside there too. The header (with location) should just be given a location to redirect too.

The second header call will replace the first one, so you can only really use one or the other:

```
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$url = str_replace('http://www.website.com/old-folder/','',$url);

header("Location: http://www.new-website/new-folder/$url");
```

OR

```
header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$url = str_replace('http://www.website.com/old-folder/','',$url);
```

Hopefully you now have something like: `news-article/full.php?=anything`

You can now do:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.new-website/new-folder/".$url);
```

But, as suggested already, its best to approach this with Htaccess instead of php.

Answer (score 0):

Best way you try with php. Just create a one temp variable. Write you own JavaScript redirection using windows.location.href. Assign those script to that temp variable and echo it.

Let's try that will help you.